# Остановка While по нажатию клавиши Python3.8

Tags: python, while, pyautogui

```
while True:
    pyautogui.press('W')
```

Есть цикл, суть в том что бы по нажатию кнопки, к примеру 'z',цикл останавливался.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала нужно вибрать как ти будеш получать нажатие клавиши.

А дальше просто ставиш мини-функцию при нажатие клавиши.

```
def stop_cicl()
    cicl=False
```

А перед етим в цикле ставиш условие 
cicl=True